# Вывод данных из mysql определенного пользователя

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Мне надо, что бы из базы выводились определенные пользователи у которых в параметре "games" написано WarFace (название базы users)

Comment: Что пытались сделать сами и что не получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT login FROM users WHERE games='WarFace'

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM users WHERE games='WarFace'");
if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
    echo '<table><tr>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Получаем строки из результата
        echo "<td>$row[login]</td>"; // и выводим их на страницу
    }
    echo '</tr></table>';
}
```

Comment: Добавил в ответ. Кстати mysql_query считается устаревшей, так что лучше используйте mysqli, а еще лучше сразу PDO

Comment: id, login это те столбцы в БД, которые вы хотите получить (возможно они у вас по другому называються). Тоесть, например у вас в БД есть столбцы id login games reputation и т.д., а вам надо только ИД пользователя и его Логин c games равным WarFace, вот вы и пишите в запросе SELECT id, login WHERE games='WarFace' ( ВЫБРАТЬ id, login ИЗ users ГДЕ games РАВНО 'WarFace'

Понятней не знаю как объяснить, может лучше книжку или статью в интернете почитайте?!

Comment: Не рботает

Comment: `
$host="";
$user="";
$password="";
$db="";
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("MySQL сервер недоступен!".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Нет соединения с БД".mysql_error());
`

Comment: нету ошибок))  Только вашь запрос у меня не работает http://prntscr.com/2r6m99

Сейчас поставил or die выдает ошибку.

`
Ошибочный запрос к БДYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'WarFace\'' at line 1
`

Comment: Ну так уберите эти \' из запроса и будет вам счастье )

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Ответьте на вопрос похожий на этот. http://hashcode.ru/questions/295905/php-личные-сообщения